# what's the reason that the same React APP renders animation in different speed in different browers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, browser

I have a React App with one circle that changes color following this table.

```
Duration/ms Color
20          red
20          yellow
...
```

I have current_index in this.state as the line number, and have the updateColor() function running in componentWillMount()

```
this.state = {current_index:0}


componentWillMount(){
    this.UpdateColor()
  }

UpdateColor(){
    this.setState({current_index : this.state.current_index+1})
    setTimeout(()=>this.updateColor,
                     time_interval_based_on_index)
}
```

However, i noticed the same code runs in significantly different speed in firefox, chrome and safari.

Why?

and how to fix that?

Many thanks

Comment: How significantly is significant? Each has different JavaScript engines - it's [very normal](https://venturebeat.com/2018/07/09/browser-benchmark-battle-july-2018-chrome-vs-firefox-vs-edge/) for them to vary.

Comment: like 1.0x vs 2.0x

Comment: Does that mean something like 2 ms to 4 ms, or 2 seconds to 4 seconds? How many iterations of your benchmark did you run to come to this conclusion?

Comment: even though they have different JS engines, the time costs of rendering a shape shouldn't be so significant, should it?

Comment: i want to have them running forever...a sleep() function would be nice, i can just iterate through the loop and move the pointer back to begining when it reaches the end. unfortunately i didn't find a way to do sleep() in js, has to call recursively with setTimeOut instead. Blowing the stack might be a thing but it hasn't happen so far

Comment: It's entirely possible for there to be major differences. Look at the benchmarks on https://venturebeat.com/2018/07/09/browser-benchmark-battle-july-2018-chrome-vs-firefox-vs-edge/2/, for example - MS Edge is **four times** faster than Firefox in the SunSpider benchmark.

Comment: interesting results. for me chrome is actually way slower than firefox.

Comment: the interval is in the range between 10ms-1000ms, and the animation in chrome is 2 times slower than firefox...

Comment: Chrome's the slowest in that benchmark, and it's going to vary a lot depending *what* you're benchmarking. If this isn't actually causing your application true *performance issues*, I'd stop worrying about variations.

Comment: Unfortunately the function of my application is playing animation users send via REST requests (facepalm). I guess I'll just suggest them using firefox since chrome is so slow ,feels like playing 0.5x :( Thanks for the info. it's very useful!

Comment: If your issue is slow animations, it's likely you can optimize *that* part instead of worrying about browser differences. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/ https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108

Comment: It looks normal on safari and firefox, only 0.5x on chrome. But thanks for the advice, ill check it out.